# Getting SEC7111 on https page trying to contact Local machine widget using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, http, security, https, xmlhttprequest

We currently have an in-house Javascript web application, delivered to the browser over HTTP/S. There’s a companion .Net application on the user’s desktop which provides some enhanced functionality that normally wouldn't be available to a purely web-based application. The desktop app provides an HTTP interface running on localhost, and the web app communicates with the desktop application via unencrypted HTTP requests.

This works fine using Chrome, Firefox, and – prior to the Windows 10 Creators update – IE11 and Edge. However, since the Creators update, the HTTP requests are being blocked with a SEC7111 Cross Origin Security error.

Using HTTPS for the local application isn’t an option. I’ve tried turning “Smart Screen” off, and adding the site to the safe zone, both to no avail.

I’m uncertain what’s changed in the most recent updates, but what’s the cross platform way of ensuring an HTTPS web application can communicate with a local application running an HTTP interface?

Here is the example code to send the initial widget session initiation;

```
 if (!testSession) {
                            var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:9645/widget?command=connect&agent=' + System.AgentName + '&password=' + $('#UserPassword').val();
                            var scr = XMLHttpRequest('http://127.0.0.1:9645/widget');
                            loggingAction('info', 'NOTIFICATION : localhost Widget connection attempt to [' + url + '].');
                            var SR1= $.post(url);
                            SR1.done(function (e) {
                                if (e.indexOf('OK') !== -1) {
                                    sR = true;
                                    loggingAction('info', 'INFORMATION : LocalHost widget active and sent response of ' + e);
                                } else {
                                    sR = false;
                                    loggingAction('warn', 'WARNING : localHost widget not active.');
                                }
                                loggingAction('info', 'NOTIFICATION : Audio connection processing complete.');
                            });
                        }
```

The error arises when the XMLHttpRequest attempts to fire.

Previously the XMLHttpResponse method was used to ensure that the port was open for the post request. The post response gets a SessionID number which is used for further comms with the widget.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by testing in Chrome with security flags set